# Collapsing pixels in my raster

Tags: qgis, raster, night-time-images

I want to use a map of VIIRS nightlights data, the annual VNL V2 2015 masked data from https://eogdata.mines.edu/products/vnl/ and overlay (intersect with) the nightlights data onto a map of various countries.

Currently, each pixel is super granular, and I'd want to make each pixel bigger (so each pixel would be ~.1 degrees long by ~.1 lat).

Is there a way to collapse/aggregate the pixels to make them bigger so I can run the pixels to polygons function & intersect my data faster?

Comment: You're looking for the term "resampling".  This can be done with e.g. gdalwarp: https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-r

Comment: Or is QGIS https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterprojections.html#gdalwarpreproject